# "Injustice - Gods Among Us - Year Six" release date?

Tags: dc, injustice

I've just read Injustice - Gods Among Us - Year Five. Last chapter(№ 40) ended up with.. (spoiler)

> Joker from alternative Earth comes to this world and meets Batman.

So, whats next? It doesn't look like the end. Is there a Year 6? If so, then when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems unlikely that there will be a Year 6. The marketing for year 5 contained the following blurb.

> **This is it: the final year and final volume of INJUSTICE: GODS AMONG
> US,** leading into the storyline of the hit video game!
>
> <sup><sub>[Random House: Injustice Year 5](http://penguinrandomhouse.ca/books/548572/injustice-gods-among-us-year-five-vol-2#9781401268848)</sub></sup>

and there's a heartfelt "goodbye" from head writer Brian Bucatello on the official DC website.

> Like many of you, I was a fan of the Injustice comic before DC asked
> me to take over the series in year three. Now I’ve come to the end of
> my journey and I feel the awesome sense of propriety that comes with
> living with beloved characters over time. In a weird way I feel like a
> proud parent whose kids are leaving the nest.
>
> I’m going to miss them.
>
> <sup><sub>[Hanging Up the Gloves: Brian Buccellato Bids Farewell to Injustice](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2016/09/20/hanging-up-the-gloves-brian-buccellato-bids-farewell-to-injustice)</sub></sup>

---

It will, however please you to hear that the adventures will continue (with much the same creative team) in a **brand new series;** [Injustice: Ground Zero](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/injustice-gods-among-us-%E2%80%94-ground-zero-2016/injustice-gods-among-us-%E2%80%94-ground-zero-1), bridging the gap between the events of the video games [Injustice: Gods Among Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injustice:_Gods_Among_Us) and [Injustice 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injustice_2)

> It’s weird to say farewell to something that’s been a part of your
> life for so long. **I’m moving on to new creative challenges and
> opportunities and won’t be taking the ride with the Jim and the gang
> as it continues in INJUSTICE: GROUND ZERO. The new series kicks off in
> October and is in great hands with the talented writer Chris Sebela.**
> As a fan of Injustice, I can’t wait to see what he does with the
> heroes and villains I had the honor of fostering for two years. Knock
> ‘em dead, Chris!
>
> <sup><sub>[Hanging Up the Gloves: Brian Buccellato Bids Farewell to Injustice](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2016/09/20/hanging-up-the-gloves-brian-buccellato-bids-farewell-to-injustice)</sub></sup>

Comment: I just don't get one thing. Will there be something like ultimate fight, outcome, real end of resistance vs regime fight in "Ground Zero"? Or is it just spin off? Because end of the year 5 really doesn't look like end at all.

Comment: @Johndoe - You'll have to buy the comics to find out. Since year 5 leads directly into the game, the game is the conclusion.